# IsPointerOverGameObject returns true for different ui text in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a canvas in unity 2d scene , Inside it I have 3 UI Text elements , I am attaching the below script to 2 of the UI elements

```
void Update()
        {if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {


                if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject ()) {


                    //Application.CaptureScreenshot("Bla.png");
                    //ShareImage(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Bla.png", "dasdas", "dsadaS", "dasdas");

                    Debug.Log ("Screenshot taken");
                }
            }
}
```

The problem is happening that If i click anything inside the canvas IsPointerOverGameObject is return always true , I created another canvas but same problem. It's like its dealing with all UI elements being clicked on each time I click any UI text element.

I am creating a menu of UI text items and each item must has it's own action , but here each time i am clicking it's firing the same action for all

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do they need to be `Text` and can't be `Buttons`? Is `Raycast target` checked?

Comment: Yes I am making them texts , and yes ray cast target is checked for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The code you attached **works** perfectly **fine** on my machine. I was able to **replicate** your problem by attaching the script to the **Canvas** which the **parent** of my text. Make sure that you did not **attach** the script to the **Canvas** but only on each individual `Text`.

If this is not the problem,there are many other ways to do this in Unity. Sometimes, some of the API don't work well because of the way your `UI` is setup. You can try the method below:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class Clicker: MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Application.CaptureScreenshot("Bla.png");
        //ShareImage(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Bla.png", "dasdas", "dsadaS", "dasdas");

        Debug.Log("Screenshot taken");
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked and the script is attached to the UI text only , my canvas design is the following : Render mode ( screen space - camera ) , UI Scale mode (Scale with screen size ) . The weird thing that happens is when I click on one ui text , it gets blue border and the other elements get grey border. I tried adding each of them in different canvas , but still having the same issue .

Comment: Canyou upload image of the canvas hierarchy?

Comment: Image added to the main question

Comment: That's weird. I see nothing wrong. What Unity version are you using? Also can you upload the scene here. I will try to fix it if you can.

Comment: This is the scene ( uploaded ) , all the texts have the same design , only the attached scripts are different. I am using unity 5.2.3f1